# How to sync iCloud calender in android app with xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, icloud-api

I want to integrate iCloud calender in my Android app with Xamarin. How to sync iCloud calender in android app with xamarin?

Comment: Search in __Google__.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily find it in google though. It's on the first listing